External app using wp-load on subdomain
I have developped an external app to manage my physical shop. I'm using couples of WordPress functions to perform some actions.
It's works great it I'm using the app from subfolder (example : domain.com/app/)
but I would use it on subdomain (example : app.domain.com) but I cannot access to it, it redirect everytime on the WordPress site : domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=app
Do you guys knows how to deal with that ?
I could use Rest API but I'm on Wordpress MultiSite contexte, I'm using 'switch_to_blog()' function... to perform some DB calls.

I don't understand the last sentence about API and multisite. If you don't have the endpoint that you need, you can write a plugin to extend the API.

I think that's getting triggered by wp-load being unable to identify which blog you're on at load time. I'd try
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

before you include wp-load, looking up the correct IDs for domain.com/app/ from your wp_blogs table.

Sorry for the confusion of my question?.
On domain.com/app/ I don't have any Wordpress installation, I have a WordPress on domain.com/
On my app, I need to call some WP functions and get some datas from the WP installed on domain.com
So :
domain.com => Wordpress
admin.domain.com => External app which display some data from WordPress

Ah OK. Then you want the site ID and blog ID of the blog you’re choosing in switch_to_blog, or if you don’t know that yet then just any valid site ID and blog ID from the table.
